# Azure Cosmos DB Custom Conflict Resolution -- conflictingItems

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working on a stored procedure for custom conflict resolution. One of the parameter -- `conflictingItems` is confusing me.

The documentation given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-conflicts?tabs=dotnetv2%2Casync#sample-custom-conflict-resolution-stored-procedure) says,

> conflictingItems: Array of the committed version of all items in the container that are conflicting with incomingItem on **ID** or any other **unique index properties**.

If I upsert an entity with a different ID, shouldn't it just create a new entity? 
Can someone provide a scenario where this `conflictingItems` will be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conflict resolution is used for Cosmos account with multi-master is enabled to handle scenarios where items with the same id or that violate unique indexes occur in multiple regions simultaneously. If you are not configured for multi-master then you do not need to do conflict resolution.

Comment: Yes we are currently converting to use multi-region write. If there are 3 write regions, and each of them is trying to upsert an entity with same ID, what are `incomingItem` and `conflictingItems` in this case?

Comment: incoming item is the item being committed in the primary region and conflicting items are those items that are conflicting with it in your other regions.